# What does it mean .files?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use detect.py to recognize licence plates from:

https://github.com/matthewearl/deep-anpr/blob/master/detect.py

I didn't understand a part.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
im = cv2.imread("plaka1.jpg")
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) / 255.

f = np.load("weights.npz")
param_vals = [f[n] for n in sorted(f.files, key=lambda s: int(s[4:]))]

for pt1, pt2, present_prob, letter_probs in post_process(
                                              detect(im_gray, param_vals)):
```

What does it mean "f.files"? It is not working because there is not ".files" method.

Comment: sorted function takes an iterable. So f.files is iterable. f is what np.load returns which is array, tuple, dict, etc. I hope that answers your qn

Comment: However "f.files" is giving warning. For exmple "f.items()" is not giving error. What is the difference?  Can I use just "f" without ".files"?